# Send Push Notification in Non English Language

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, notifications

I am working on Push Notification App. In that, I want to send Push Notification in Non English language like Gujrathi Lang.(Indian Regional Lang.) But when I receive notification in Gujrathi Language it was showing "??????" in Payload Push Message. But when I send Notification in English everything works fine messages are shown properly. I can't understand why it is happen As I'm first time working on Push notification.

Is there any Problem from my Server Side or I have to handle the Localized string from my app? At which end the problem is arise?

Need Valuable suggestions

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is found and it was from my server side changed in notification  Payload